# JavaScript to pass Multiple jpegs from Flash (AS3) to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, actionscript-3, flash, image-uploading

I have the following AS3 code which converts a bunch of BitMap screenshots to jepgs following a user request. (sourceArray stores the original bitmaps).

```
for (var i:int=0; i<sourceArray.length; i++)
    {
    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(10);
    var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(sourceArray[i]);
    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");     
    var jpgURLRequest:String = new String("videoprocess.php?name=drawing" + i +".jpg");
    jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
    jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
    ExternalInterface.call("openWindow", jpgURLRequest );
```

My PHP code to save these jpegs is as follows:

```
 <?php
 if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] ) && isset ( $_GET['name'] ) ) {

//the image file name
$fileName = time();

// get the binary stream
$im = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

//write it
$fp = fopen($fileName, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $im);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Using the externalinterface.call call above, I'm trying to pass individual jpegs to the PHP file for saving on each turn of the loop, but so far I've been unable to pass the jpgURLRequest as an object. Would anyone be kind to enough to shed light on the JS code which would be needed to pass the jpeg from AS3 to PHP? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see why you would want to use Javascript to pass the binary data from Flash to PHP. You ca do that from as3 using [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) and [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) and setting the method to "post". The code you should add looks like this:

```
var urlRequest = new URLRequest(jpgURLRequest);
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = jpgStream;
urlRequest.requestHeaders = new Array(header);
var urlLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
//depending if you want to do something with the response you can add event listeners
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**
If you want to send the requests in order you should start by defining a global variable: `var index:int=0` and define a function:

```
function loadSource() {
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(10);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(sourceArray[index]);
//... rest of your code here  
var urlRequest = new URLRequest(jpgURLRequest);
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = jpgStream;
urlRequest.requestHeaders = new Array(header);
var urlLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeEventListener);}

function completeEventListener(e:Event)
{
  index ++;
  if (index<sourceArray.length) loadSource();}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion. When I integrated your code into mine and ran the app on my local server, only the final screenshot is sent to PHP and saved. I think this may have something to do with urlLoader only being able to execute once per frame. Do you know of any way around this limitation?

Comment: I dont know of a such limitation. Maybe the server saves the files with the same name (as I see you use time()). To verify you could try to add a random sequence of characters at the name or send a the name in the request (either as GET by appending ?name=blabla or as a request header).

Comment: I just used GET to alter the file names per your suggestion, but still no luck. I've read here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703962/how-to-make-synchronous-url-requests-from-actionscript) that urlLoader is asynchronous and therefore doesn't function well in loops -- might this be the problem?

Comment: The solution I see to overcome this (although all the requests should arrive to the server) is instead of using a for to iterate through the sourceArray, implement a complete event listener and each time it is called to send the next element from sourceArray. I will update the answer with the corresponding code to be more clear.

Comment: Fabulous! I'm now seeing all of the captured images sent correctly to my php script and downloaded to the server. I really can't thank you enough for all of your help -- you made my day!